# Strange Keyboard Bug

Tags: raspbian, keyboard

I recently installed Raspbian onto my pi and I started to experience a strange keyboard bug. I was able to get it to work just fine for about an hour, and I was on my way to setting up SSH and all of a sudden my keyboard stopped working. I restarted the pi and they keyboard worked again for about 5 minutes and then died on me. This continued after every reboot, so I reinstalled Raspbian onto the SD card and now the keyboard won't work at all. I am using a Monoprice K11 USB Keyboard. I tested the keyboard on my Mac and it said that it wasn't recognized, and I had to tell my Mac that it was an ANSI keyboard for it to work.

This keyboard is not on the compatible devices list, but I thought that given the nature of the error that it was something besides the keyboard. The pi is recognizing the keyboard, it shows up during boot.

Do you think that this is an error with keyboard compatibility, or something else? And does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried a different, or compatible keyboard? This would rule out the Pi being the problem. Try using a powered hub, possibly a lack of power.

Comment: I would second the idea for a lack of power. Using underpowered cords with a higher draw keyboard causes exactly these kinds of issues.

Comment: I would agree with the others. Here's the list of verified powered USB hubs if you're unsure of which one to buy: http://elinux.org/RPi_Powered_USB_Hubs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I had many issues with my Pi freezing or rebooting with my Mac keyboard, which also acted as a USB hub. What I did was power the Pi with a Power USB hub; a cable from the main powered plug to the Pi, then a cable going from the Pi to the hub so I can use other devices.

I used a D-Link Powered USB hub, specifically, instead of a cheap one. It stays running, and I plug in devices to the hub. Right now, the only thing plugged in to the Pi's USB is the hub, and a basic Microsoft Mouse.

Depending on how you set up your Pi, or what it's for though, you may be able to get away with using just SSH for using it. That won't require a keyboard to be hooked up until there's something really wrong with it though.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as correct because I'm almost 100% it's a power issue. The critical piece of information I was missing is the fact that I also had a mouse plugged in, and when I unplugged it, the keyboard worked. A verified, powered hub would solve my problem.